# Opening an Excel document outside of browser with IIS 6

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, iis-6

I have links to various Excel documents on an intranet site. I want these documents to open in **Excel** and not within the browser but i cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

In IIS 5 i could do this by setting the href to point to a shortcut file (.lnk). With IIS 6, the shortcut files generate 404 errors. (This is with Excel 2003, FYI).

I should also note that the browser in question is IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works similarly to IIS5. Instead of using an http:// href link, i used a file:// link to a shortcut (.lnk) file on a network share. This prompts the user to open the file and opens it in Excel if selected.

Comment: Do note, however, that security does not happen in IIS here but rather on the network share.  There are also domain issues to consider in larger environments.

Answer (score 0):

It's a client-side setting and not controllable by the web server.  On the client side you go into Folder Options from Windows Explorer (*not* IE), go to the File Types tab, scroll down to the .XLS extension and uncheck Browse In Same Window.  This is true for any MS Office format.

Comment: I didn't want to modify user settings if i didn't have to, but this solution does work. I found another way around it though.